# Trying to get async to work in a Windows C++ application

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I can't seem to understand why this won't work. I've searched endlessly and don't see how my example below doesn't kick off an asynchronous operation.

```
void Folder::NewFileAction()
{
     if (Folder::Match) 
     {
         LOG(LOG_INFO) << "New file detected. Compressing";
         auto Compress = async(launch::async, &ZipFile, Folder::FilePath);
     }
}
```

Shouldn't this kick off an asynchronous operation in another thread? Is there a flag I have to enable in Visual Studio 2015?

Thank you

Comment: How did you determine it doesn't launch an asynchronous operation?

Comment: It is continuing to block execution on the method that invokes NewFileAction(). Multiple files will come in simultaneously but do not get processed until the compression is done.

Comment: That could be because `Compress` goes out of scope. Read the docs for `std::future`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::async` returns a `std::future` object. Since `Compress` is local object (of type `std::future`), and will go out of scope. Since this is only object holding the `async` return result, the destructor will keep on waiting. You should keep such object(s) in member of this class (a `vector<future>` may be).

Comment: So should I use a vector to keep track of the objects and add them as a member of the class itself?